# Symfony debug bar and IE8

Tags: css, symfony

I am working with a symfony 2 project. I am in development environment and the symfony debug bar displays well with any browser but IE8. It looks like the css for this bar is not loaded with  IE.

After investigation, the problem occurs after the 2.0 version (so for 2.1 and 2.2)... maybe web debug bar css is CSS3, it would be quite an error to do for Sensio Labs.. I dont believe it

Comment: why do you care? why would you ever use IE while debugging symfony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed an issue, a bug of Symfony versions above 2.0 : the web debug toolbar is not displayed properly with IE8.

This issue has been reported, and a solution given

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7422#issuecomment-15112627